# Trouble fading divs with .each() function after ajax request?

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax, each

At the moment my divs load in one by one on page load. It's absolutely fine! Though when I make an ajax request and then `append(data)` to the same container my code then loops through all of the divs on the page rather than the newly added divs?

My question is: how would I perform the same `.each()` effect on only the newly added ajax success data?

jQuery:

```
success: function(data){
    $('#profileLinks').append(data);  

    $('.eachLink').each(function(i) {
        $(this).fadeOut(0).delay(100*i).fadeIn(500);
    }); 

}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="profileLinks" class="floatLeft">
    <div class="eachLink floatLeft">Div 1</div>
    <div class="eachLink floatLeft">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $data = $(data);
$data.find(".eachLink").addClass("not-animated-yet").appendTo("#profileLinks");
$(".eachLink.not-animated-yet").each(/* your animation function */);
```

Comment: It's maybe just me but this doesn't work. Should I be putting this in between the parentheses `$(this).fadeOut(0).delay(100*i).fadeIn(500);`

Comment: @learn you need to wrap it not only in those parentheses but also `function () {}`

Comment: I tried this aswell but no luck and there are not any errors within developers tools either.

Comment: @learn not without seeing the entire code in action.  Perhaps set up a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry unsure how to get js working on jsfiddle. No time to mess around with it! Is their nothing you can see which would be stopping your code from working?

Answer (score 0):

You could try removing the class attribute:

```
success: function(data){
    $('#profileLinks').append(data);  

    $('.eachLink').each(function(i) {
        $(this).removeClass(".eachLink");
        $(this).fadeOut(0).delay(100*i).fadeIn(500);
    }); 

}
```

Comment: This doesn't sort anything at all unfortuneately